# docker run is failing

Tags: linux, docker

I'm seeing below error with docker running in rhel7 on top of virtual box

I'm just trying to use `hello-world` image

```
[root@localhost ~]# docker run hello-world
docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:348: starting container process caused "exec: \"/hello\": stat /hello: no such file or directory": unknown.
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. You should use another site on the [Stack Exchange network](https://stackexchange.com/sites) for this question.

Comment: Did you pulled the image from docker hub or did you build it by your Dockerfile? It seems you got an "ello-world" image without /hello script (or it hasn't execution permissions)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you may not have execute rights where you are trying to run the Docker.
Try using a directory that you have execute rights to such as your Home directory.

Or you may need to run the `chmod +x` on the directory you are running the docker command on.

Answer (score 0):

try this command

```
sudo service docker restart
```

it usually helps in Ubuntu

Answer (score 0):

The / cannot be used as a volume.

change \"/hello\": to \"hello\":

I suppose it is in Dockerfile?

check fromlatest.io for Dockerfile errors